# How can I merge multiple PDF files in a specific order that is based on a reference file/array in Python using PyPDF?

Tags: python, pypdf

**Objective:**

I want to merge multiple PDF files (100s perhaps) in a specific order that is not based on the alphabetical order of file names?

**Details:**

1. File names are generated sequentially with a universal prefix, unique identifier, and file type name. For example CA_1234_Shopping List.pdf, CA_1234_Phone Bill.pdf, CA_1234_Water Bill.pdf, and so on depending on how many file types may be applicable to [1234] family. Additionally, there may be more than one of the same file type applicable for [1234] family. Like, CA_1234_Phone Bill Son.pdf, CA_1234_Phone Bill Daughter.pdf, CA_1234_Phone Bill Wife.pdf.
2. The case presented above can be expanded to many more "families". Such as CA_4563_[file type].pdf
3. Also important, each of these file types are multi page files, so the intention is not split individual files at all.
4. There is a reference list that contains file types such as Phone Bill, Water Bill, On Demand TV Service Bill, Subscription Type 1 Bill, and so on. There may be a list of so many file types, which any given time, any given family may or may not have all file types. In most cases, the set of file types of a family would be a [somewhat random] subset of file types listed in this reference file. In other words, our reference file can contain 500 file types listed, where a family may have only 10 file types.
5. What is important about this reference file is that the file types are not listed in alphabetical order, but in an order we want the files to be.

**Question:**

In a folder where there may be 100s of families with 10s of file types where each would have different set of files and/or different number of these file types. Because the file names are generated by the computer sequentially, they are in alphabetical order in the directory.

I want to be able to search through this directory, identify each family and combine all of their files based on the specific order defined in the reference list above in a single pdf file. And I want to do this for all families.

**Attempted Solution:**

Using Python with PyPDF along with OS (for the simplest use case of one and only one family):

File_Type_Reference_File.txt

File_type_1
File_type_2
...........
File_type_n

Read this file into into Python

```
reference = open("File_Type_Reference_File.txt", 'r')

ordered_file_type_list = []

for line in reference:
    ordered_file_type_list.append(line(strip))

-- At this point I want to compare the actual pdf files in my directory (and thus their file names) against this reference list. And I want to start combining/merging these individual pdf files into a single output pdf file according to the order defined in the list.--

from PyPDF import PdfReader, PdfWriter, PdfMerger

directory = os.getcwd()

for file os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
       pdf_file = PdfReader(file)
       pdf_file.decrypt("filepassword")


pdf_merger = PdfMerger()

for line in ordered_file_type_list:
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        ---this is the blocker point need to be figured out---
        pdf_merger.append(file)
pdf_merger.write("CA_1234_Family_Combined_File_Package.pdf")
pdf_merger.close
```

This has not been successful so far.

How can I resolve this problem and scale it up for multiple "family" sets.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need Python for this.  There are excellent command line tools for manipulating PDF files (pdftk, ConcurrentPDF).  You can use Python to write a simple batch file or shell script to do the real work.